# I am having a issue in the following code. Why is the line printf("maximum value of g(x)) is not getting printed

Tags: arrays, c

The problem statement is given below:

I was trying to calculate the part V of the problem statement first. I tried to write the code but the last `printf` statement is  not getting executed.

I've attached details of my problems statement above.

[image][image]

As you can explicitly see I expected `printf` to get printed but it didn't  get printed.

The code written below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const float pi = 3.141;

int main() {

  int N,
    i,
    j,
    xnot,
    xone,
    M;
  int k = 0;

  printf("Enter the number of functional values required\n");
  scanf("%d", &N);
  printf("N=%d", N);

  float w[N],
    A[N],
    f[N],
    phi[N],
    sum,
    term;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("enter the value of w %d\n", i);
    scanf("%f",  &w[i]);

    printf("enter the value of A %d\n", i);
    scanf("%f",  &A[i]);

    printf("enter the value of f %d\n", i);
    scanf("%f",  &f[i]);

    printf("enter the value of phi %d\n", i);
    scanf("%f",  &phi[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("w%d=%f ,A%d=%f ,f%d=%f ,phi%d=%f\n",
           i, w[i], i, A[i], i, f[i], i, phi[i]);
  }

  printf("Enter x0,x1,M respectively\n");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &xnot, &xone, &M);
  printf("The values of x0,x1 and M are %d,%d,%d respectively\n", xnot, xone, M);

  float stor_val[N];
  for (int d = xnot; d <= xone; d += M) {
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      term = w[i] * A[i] * (sin((2 * pi * f[i] * (d)) + phi[i]));
      sum = sum + term;
    }

    stor_val[d] = sum;
  }

  float max = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    if (max < stor_val[j]) {
      max = stor_val[j];
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (max == stor_val[i]) {
      printf("The maximum value of the function g(x) is %f at x = %d\n", max, i);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of bounds in `stor_val[d]=sum;` In your example `stor_val` was defined with `2` elements, but `d` varies along `10`, `33`, `56`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In testing your initial code and adding some "printf" statements, I was coming across some undefined and out-of-bounds issues with the arrays being used to store values and subsequently derive a maximum value as noted in the good comments.  After doing the initial correction for the out-of-bounds issue and doing a test run, all of the values being stored were negative numbers, which would cause the program to skip printing any maximum value.  After reviewing the apparent assignment instructions, regarding trig functions and data points, I believe the following refactored code gets close to the desired functionality of the assignment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const float pi = 3.141;

int main()
{

    int N, i, j, xnot, xone, M;
    int k = 0;                      // Used this variable with scanf() to eliminate compiler warnings

    printf("Enter the number of functional values required: ");     // General cleanup of input requests
    k = scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("N=%d\n", N);

    float w[N], A[N], f[N], phi[N], sum, term;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("enter the value of w %d ", i);
        k = scanf("%f",  &w[i]);

        printf("enter the value of A %d ", i);
        k = scanf("%f",  &A[i]);

        printf("enter the value of f %d ", i);
        k = scanf("%f",  &f[i]);

        printf("enter the value of phi %d ", i);
        k = scanf("%f",  &phi[i]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("w%d = %f, A%d = %f, f%d = %f, phi%d = %f\n", i, w[i], i, A[i], i, f[i], i, phi[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter x0, x1, M respectively ");
    k = scanf("%d %d %d", &xnot, &xone, &M);
    if (k == 3)
        printf("The values of x0, x1, and M are %d, %d, %d respectively\n", xnot, xone, M);

    float stor_val[M];                      // Changed this sizing to the number of data points between xnot and xone
    for (int d = 0; d < M; d++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)             // So that array usage starts at element zero
        {
            term = w[i] * A[i] * (sin((2 * pi * f[i] * (xone + (float) d * ((xone - xnot) / ((float)M - 1.00)))) + phi[i]));    // Believe this is the formula to derive each data point
            sum += term;
        }

        stor_val[d] = sum;
        //printf("Stored value: %f\n", stor_val[d]);
    }

    float max = 0.00;
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        if (max < stor_val[j])
        {
            max = stor_val[j];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        if (max == stor_val[i])
        {
            printf("The maximum value of the function g(x) is %f at x = %d\n", max, i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The key items to note are:

- The size of the "stor_val" array is set to match the number of data points desired ("M").
- The associated "for" loops for deriving stored values are revised to align with the number of data points.
- The formula utilizing the sine function is revised so as to derive a value at each data point.  Note the comments added in to point out and clarify the reasons for the refinements.

Also, just to make the entry of data a bit more intuitive, some refinement of the prompting was done, along with the utilization of a previously unused variable (int k) with the "scanf" statements just to mitigate and remove compiler warnings.

With those refactored bits, following was a test run of the program at the terminal utilizing the aforementioned input data.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/MaxValue/bin/Release$ ./MaxValue 
Enter the number of functional values required: 2
N=2
enter the value of w 0 .9
enter the value of A 0 7.4
enter the value of f 0 45
enter the value of phi 0 1.3

enter the value of w 1 1.4
enter the value of A 1 4.8
enter the value of f 1 10
enter the value of phi 1 -1.3

w0 = 0.900000, A0 = 7.400000, f0 = 45.000000, phi0 = 1.300000
w1 = 1.400000, A1 = 4.800000, f1 = 10.000000, phi1 = -1.300000
Enter x0, x1, M respectively 10 75 23
The values of x0, x1, and M are 10, 75, 23 respectively
The maximum value of the function g(x) is 11.933567 at x = 5
```

This being my first glance at the apparent program assignment, there might have been some bits of misinterpretation, but the main obstacle of having undefined and out-of-bounds issues should be answered and any other program refinements can progress from there.

The biggest take-away from both the previous good comments and this refactored code is be cognizant of how array definitions should be handled.  And as always, it may be wise to refer to some tutorials on the "C" language, especially as it pertains to arrays.